# How do I navigate between directories in terminal?

Tags: command-line, directory

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu and have tried changing to folders/directories with some difficulty.

Could someone explain why the following commands failed to change to the desired target folder/directory?

```
sharon@sharon:~$ cd Home 
bash: cd: Home: No such file or directory 
sharon@sharon:~$ cd /Home 
bash: cd: /Home: No such file or directory 
sharon@sharon:~$ cd Documents 
sharon@sharon:~/Documents$ cd Downloads 
bash: cd: Downloads: No such file or directory 
sharon@sharon:~/Documents$ cd /Downloads 
bash: cd: /Downloads: No such file or directory 
sharon@sharon:~/Documents$
```

Answer (score 41):

The filesystem is GNU/Linux is like a tree, except that the root is on top. :-) So you have structure like:

```
/
  bin/
  home/
    sharon/
      Documents/
      Downloads/
      fileA.txt
      fileB.jpg
  usr/
  var/
```

If you want to move inside the tree, one option is to use relative paths. If you are in `/home/sharon`, then typing `cd Downloads` will work, because Downloads is an immediate child of your current directory. If you are in the subfolder `Documents` and want to change directory (`cd`) to `Downloads`, you have to go up (`..`) and then to `Downloads`. So the correct command would be `cd ../Downloads`.

You could also enter an absolute path. So the `Downloads` folder is a subfolder of `sharon` which is a subfolder of `home` which is … (you get the idea :-))
So you can also enter `cd /home/sharon/Downloads` wherever you are in the filesystem.

- `~` always refers to the home directory of the current user (`/home/sharon` in your case). If you enter `cd ~/Downloads` you'll land in your `Downloads` folder.
- `.` refers to the current directory, so `cd ./Downloads` is roughly equivalent to `cd Downloads`.
- `..` means "parent directory".
- `/` at the beginning of file path refers to the root directory.

The next nice thing is tab expansion. If you enter `cd ~/Dow`<kbd>Tab</kbd> (last is pressing Tabulator key), the bash automatically expands it to `cd ~/Downloads`.

As the others said GNU/Linux is case sensitive. So it makes a difference if you enter `Home`, `hOme` or `home`. Furthermore I hope that you see now that there is a difference between `/home` and `home`. The first is adressed absolute while the last is relative to your current directory.

Comment: @ qbi: Wow, you're awesome. I love your detailed explanation on how to navigate among folders/directories. Are you a teacher or professor in an educational institution? Most IT guys know a lot of IT stuff but breaking concepts down to manageable and "digestible" chunks so that newbies can understand is only within the grasp of a handful but gifted guys like you.

Comment: @n00b If you found this answer helpful, you can "accept" it by clicking the V to the left of it.

Answer (score 8):

```
sharon@sharon:~$ cd Home 
bash: cd: Home: No such file or directory
```

The little cedilla ~ indicates you are already in your /home/sharon directory. When you ask for 'cd Home' the terminal looks for /home/sharon/Home. There is none.

```
sharon@sharon:~$ cd /Home 
bash: cd: /Home: No such file or directory
```

Now you are asking, given the leading slash, to go to a directory above the current location; that is /home/Home. There is none.

```
sharon@sharon:~$ cd Documents 
sharon@sharon:~/Documents$
```

Success!

```
sharon@sharon:~/Documents$ cd /Downloads 
bash: cd: /Downloads: No such file or directory
```

I'm not too sure where exactly this is. If you want to change from /home/sharon/Documents to /home/sharon/Downloads, please try:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

If you want to go directly to your home directory, that is /home/sharon, simply do:

```
cd
```

Also you can go Step back with

```
cd ..
```

And you can print the directory you are working in with (print working directory)

```
pwd
```

Comment: @ chili555: Thanks a lot for helping newbies like me. Merry Christmas to you and your loved ones.

Comment: The leading slash indicates a path relative to the root, not one above the current directory.  That would be `../`

Answer (score 3):

The command tells you why: There is no such directory.

Filenames are case sensetive, so it is /home, not /Home.  Without a leading slash, it is assumed to be relative to the current directory, and the Downloads directory is not in ~/Documents, nor is it in /, but in your home directory, to which `~` is a shortcut, thus it is ~/Documents.

Comment: @ psusi: Thanks to you, too. Merry Christmas to you and your loved ones.

Comment: @ psusi: What does the leading slash mean?

Comment: @ psusi: What does ./<filename> mean?

Comment: @noob, `/` means start from the root directory and `.` means the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer over this, because i can't comment on answers -.-

> What does the leading slash mean? – n00b

it means that the thin you are talking about is a directory not a file. Files don't have to have file endings like in Windows, so `~/thisIsAFile` would be a file in your home-directory but `~/thisIsAFile/` would be a directory/ a folder.

> What does ./ mean? – n00b

That means that the file you want to access is in your current directory.

Other usefull tips:

You can go a folder back with

```
cd ..
```

And you can get the path you are in with (print working directory)

```
pwd
```

Comment: @ a2r: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't know that files don't have file extensions like in Microsoft Windows. Do programs have file extensions in Ubuntu too?

Comment: Generally not, the system doesn't care what endings a file has, if its marked as executable ( google about chmod ) then you can run it as a programm.
Also there is a global variable (google about it) called $PATH there are a view directories saved (you can see which there are with `echo $PATH`). And when you try to run a program like you type `gedit` in the terminal. Your system looks throw the folders in $PATH and searches for gedit.

Comment: That would be a trailing slash, not a leading slash.  Also you must have a space in there before the `..`.

Comment: @ psusi: Sorry. I'm a bit confused here. What's a trailing slash? leading slash? Examples please? Thanks in advance.