# Home directory(?)

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, home-directory

I'm learning bash code, and if I try to

```
cd /Home
```

I have this error:

```
bash: cd: Home: Not a directory
```

If I run:

```
ls -lh (in /)
```

The Home "directory" has these features:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 479K Sep 23 17:09 Home
```

Is it normal or I did a mistake?

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I navigate between directories in terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/232442/how-do-i-navigate-between-directories-in-terminal)

Comment: Are you sure it's 'Home', and not 'home'? `cd /home` should work, but /Home really does not exist.

Comment: Home directory should always be lowercase /home   not /Home

Comment: You are right! I usually get into home with 'cd ~'  and the correct directory is whit lowercase "h".  I have a .deb file called Home that I thought it was the directory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get into your "Home directory" you need to run

```
cd ~
```

or

```
cd $HOME
```

or

```
cd /home/$USER
```

Home directory of the current user is located at `/home/<user_name>`. The current user name is stored in `USER` variable. The path to the home directory is stored in `HOME` variable.

Comment: You can also just type `cd` in most places.